# How do I install and configure Btrfs for desktop use on two mirrored drives?

Tags: partitioning, mount, filesystem, raid, btrfs

I would like to use [Btrfs](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) on two mirrored drives ([RAID 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1)), used for archive data on a desktop system (media files, etc.), for redundancy/availability and potential self-healing functionality in case of a drive failure.

This implies that I don't want any additional (server-oriented) functionality, such as deduplication, file compression or ARC on the filesystem, which should reduce the resource demands on a regular desktop system with more limited CPU and RAM headroom, compared to NAS or server systems.

How do I correctly setup Btrfs with the core functionality and none of these additional, more demanding features on a recent Ubuntu system (18.04+)? What else could be configured to reduce the consumption of system resources?

I have read various guides and *think* I know how to install Btrfs and that most of these features are not enabled by default, but since a correct initial setup is very important in this case, I would like to make absolutely sure there are no misunderstandings or differences in the Ubuntu-specific setup.

Detailed questions:

1. Is it enought to install btrfs-tools to set this up or is something else needed, also for scrubbing and defragmentation?
2. You mention that the disks can be used with or without partitions, what are the (dis)advantages of either option?
3. Do you happen to know whether any kind of (L2) adaptive replacement cache is being used by default? (I would rather defragment regularly instead of setting aside RAM for it.)
4. You wrote that lzo-compression will increase (read/write?) speeds, without going into too much detail, how does this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use partitioning or not while using btrfs.

With partitioning first create partition tables and partitions on both disks. Lets say `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1`.

Then create `btrfs` filesystem by running

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

You are done.

**Note:** *The previous command creates a `btrfs` filesystem on specified partitions. You don't need to "format" it neither before nor after running this command. `mkfs.btrfs` is fully sufficient to create a filesystem.*

Now you can mount this raid to any directory you like by

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mount_directory
```

You can mount either of disks with the same result: the raid will be mounted.

You can mount it permanently in `/etc/fstab`. If you don't set specific options there, like compression, they won't be used.

Alternatively you don't have to create partitions and can directly create raid on devices by:

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs -m raid1 -d raid1 /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

There is no much difference between both methods, but I prefer to have partitions traditionally.

I am not aware of any settings that will "reduce the consumption of system resources". The kernel module doesn't consume much by itself. If you don't need any features like deduplication or compression simply don't use them.

But take in account that `lzo` compression in most cases speeds up the disks and also increase storage space, because decompression is faster than reading from disk.

Answering detailed questions:

1. `btrfs-tools` is installed by default and nothing else is needed to manage `btrfs` filesystem.
2. There is no much difference if you plan to use your disks only for the raid. It doesn't affect performance in any way. But if you create partition tables on disks, you'll be able to shrink your btrfs raid partition one one or both disks and create some other filesystem(s) on part of the disk(s). It adds a bit of flexibility for the future. You can shrink btrfs partitions even when a disk is in use.
3. I am not aware of any available for a user settings regarding L2 cache usage. You can do a manual or automatic defragmentation. There is `autodefrag` mount option available for automatic defragmentation. I didn't notice much RAM usage with `autodefrag`, but that's need testing if RAM is a real problem.
4. You can mount your raid with `compress=lzo` option. If you do it on an empty raid, all files will be compressed. You can also enable compression later, but in that case already existing data won't be automatically compressed, only new data will. But you can always do a defragmentation of the existing data with `-clzo` option. That will compress the existing data.

I always use `lzo` because it adds some performance for HDDs, saves some read/write cycles for SSDs and gives extra space for both.

Example of `fstab` entry with `autodefrag` and `lzo`:

```
UUID=xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx /mount_point btrfs compress=lzo,autodefrag 0 0
```

UUID can be taken from `sudo blkid` or `gparted`.

This way you compress the filesystem with `lzo`:

```
sudo btrfs fi defrag -r -v -clzo /mount_point
```

Comment: Thanks for this walk-through, a couple of questions: 1. Is it enought to install `btrfs-tools` to set this up or is something else needed, also for scrubbing and defragmentation? 2. You mention that the disks can be used with or without partitions, what are the (dis)advantages of either option? 3. Do you happen to know whether any kind of (L2) adaptive replacement cache is being used by default? (I would rather defragment regularly instead of setting aside RAM for it.) 4. You wrote that lzo-compression will increase (read/write?) speeds, without going into too much detail, how does this work?

Comment: I added these to your question. I am editing the answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answers! The UUID that you mention for fstab, will that be created with the Btrfs volume and listed under `blkid` afterward or is it one of the paritions/volumes used to create the RAID?

Comment: You can take UUID from blkid or instead of `UUID=....` use device path like `/dev/sdb1`.

Comment: If you mount one of the disks, the whole raid will mount.

Comment: Alright. I've seen some people mount Btrfs with `defaults`, you haven't included that in your `fstab`, is that advisable at all?

Comment: `dafaults` is not needed for a long time. I had it before and removed it when wrote this answer ;-) `deafults` is only needed if no other options are mentioned. In other cases they apply "by default". But there is no harm if you have it there.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, I actually got another small question as I was about to format my drives. If I choose to partition the drives, what filesystem should I select for the partitions? Btrfs? Or does it even matter?

Comment: @Prototype700 Sure, select `btrfs`.

Comment: Hi Pilot6, I just edited your answer and added a few notes on the initial partitioning, I hope you're fine with that. - I haven't noticed the `No Filesystem` option in GNOME Disks at first and formatted the partitions as Btrfs, however mkfs.btrfs was not happy with this and canceled, unfortunately only after formatting one of the drives. On my second try, I got an obscure "magic superblock strings"-Error that read more like a bad joke. After some research I found out that the Btrfs-Wiki recommends wiping the drives with `wipefs` beforehand. After doing so, everything worked.

Comment: Well, I rejected the edit, not noticed that it was you. I never use Gnome Disks for this kind of tasks. I suggest using `gparted`. You won't have problems with that. And I see no reason of formatting twice by Gnome Disks AND `mkfs.btrfs`. If you followed my answer without any "additions" all would work well. I presumed that there was no filesystems on your disks, because I wrote about creating of partition tables.

Comment: Why would you format your partitions before running `mkfs.btrfs`? This command does all you need.

Comment: @ Pilot6, Ah okay, here's where the miscommunication happened: When I asked about which filesystem to select on Nov 27, I assumed by your answer that I had to create the partitions beforehand. I hadn't realised that specifying `/dev/sdX#` will create that new partition and had assumed they needed to already exist on the drive. Your added note should suffice in clearing this up. However, is it possible to specify the size of the partition this way? In my case, I actually had 2 and 3 TB drives with the intent on upgrading the 2 TB drive as soon as it would fail or I needed the additional space.

Comment: Regarding the Superblock-Error: I do not believe that this could have been prevented by using `gparted` or any other partition program. It was difficult for me to find any sources on the error message online, but I found out that it had to do with leftover filesystem blocks on the beginning of the drive. The Btrfs-Wiki recommends wiping them with `wipefs -a /dev/sdX`, which just removing previous partitions and creating a partition table will not do (and I had done that beforehand). I remember in the Debian Net-Installer once, it could still find a Btrfs-RAID after re-formatting the drives.

Comment: `wipefs` may be useful. I didn't dig deep but creating a new partition table in `gparted` should do the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101689/discussion-between-pilot6-and-prototype700).